# Зачем придумали RFC5261, если существует XSLT?

Tags: xml

RFC5261 - содержит описание формата для XML-патчей. Но в принципе, XSLT ведь тоже позволяет преобразовать один XML-документ в другой? Что помешало им использовать существующий стандарт? Это NIH-синдром?

При помощи XSLT можно выполнять замены:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351008/xsltcan-i-update-value-in-xml-node-using-xslt
и это не у одного меня такой вопрос - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771351/xml-diff-how-to-generate-xml-diff-using-xslt

Comment: [Обязательная картинка](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png)

Comment: А ещё XQuery есть...

Comment: XQuery не в тему в этом вопросе. Я серьезно спрашиваю, может какая есть преграда (obstacle). Хотя казалось бы, XSLT - тьюринг-полный и контент в нём любой может содержаться...

Comment: я пожалуй, ещё один вопрос задам - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/451932/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-xslt-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-xml-%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: XSLT слишком громоздкий. Как и XML сам по себе. Вот и стали появляться более компактные версии.

Comment: _XQuery не в тему в этом вопросе_ - ещё как в тему. XSLT и XQuery появились примерно в одно время и предназначены для одной цели. Их разделение на "информационно-ориентированный" и "документо-ориентированный" - не более чем словоблудие. А то, что они применяются в разных областях - это воля случая.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*RFC5261(An Extensible Markup Language (XML) Patch Operations Framework Utilizing  XML Path Language (XPath) Selectors)* - предложенный компанией Nokia декларативный формат на базе XML, созданный прежде всего для использования в HTTP-методе PATCH.

При помощи всего 3-х тегов-операторов, он позволяет приложению задавать инструкции, с помощью которых веб-сервис(REST) должен будет изменить некий документ на сервере.

Обработка этого простого формата занимает буквально пару сотню строчек кода, и при грамотной реализации, он позволяет выполнять сразу множество параллельных изменений в одном документе при обработке множества различных HTTP-запросов PATCH.

---

*XSLT(XSL Transformations)* - созданный консорциумом W3C формат на базе XML, предназначенный для описания инструкций по созданию из документов одного формата, документов в формате другом.

Это огромный, тяжело реализуемый формат, предназначенный для решения задач совсем другого рода, а именно - для массовых преобразований XML-документов из одного формата в другой.