# Как имея два XML-файла получить XSLT-файл преобразующий первый XML во второй?

Tags: xml

Я просто хочу получить эдакий одноразовый diff/patch. Всё что я хочу - готовую утилиту, которая берет какой-нибудь алгоритм Tekli, применяет его ко входному xml (два входных файла - в состоянии до и после редактирования) и редактирующую последовательность сериализует в XSLT (третий **конкретный** файл, с конкретными изменениями, который можно применить только к одному конкретному исходному файлу (в состоянии до редактирования), чтобы получить файл в состоянии после редактирования).

Хотелось бы обратить внимание, что так как всё конкретное, то никакие дополнительные схемы для xml не требуются. И много раз я этот XSLT к разным входным файлам я тоже применять не собираюсь.

А, да, и обратное преобразование из второго в первый мне тоже не нужно.

Что ещё мне не нужно, я пока не знаю, дополню позднее по вашим уточняющим вопросам.

Какие утилиты можно для этого использовать, как их вызывать?
Какими командами потом получить из первого файла и XSLT второй файл?

Почему я хочу именно XSLT, а не какой-нибудь RFC5261 ? Потому что для XSLT есть утилиты для его накатывания в каждом утюге, а для RFC5261 надо устанавливать дополнительно. Вот тут список XSLT-процессоров, чтобы применить патч - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info

Почему я не хочу использовать простые diff и patch? Ну потому что они не понимают структуру XML. В работах Microsoft данная тема подробно раскрыта, не буду сюда копировать.

Вопрос в том, как этот патч создать. Потому что разные утилиты сравнения XML, которые попадаются, создают файлы разниц в своих уникальных форматах (например Diffgram), а совсем не в XSLT.

ПРИМЕР КОДА, который я ожидаю увидеть (примерный):

создание патча:

```
~ $ xmldiff --format=xslt myxmlfile-v1.0.xml myxmlfile-v1.1.xml >patch-for-myxmlfile-v1.0-v1.1.xslt
```

применение патча:

```
~ $ xmlpatch --format=xslt myxmlfile-v1.0.xml patch-for-myxmlfile-v1.0-v1.1.xslt >myxmlfile-v1.1.xml
```

ну и ссылку на пакет(ы), в которых эти xmldiff и xmlpatch распространяются.

Некоторые работы с описаниями алгоритмов:

- 2013, Байцерова Юлия Сергеевна, под руководством Вояковская Н.Н., Проверка избыточности и минимизация множества тестов

  http://se.math.spbu.ru/SE/YearlyProjects/2013/YearlyProjects/2013/445/445-Baytserova-report.pdf
- 2012, Д. В. Луцив, Д. В. Кознов, В. С. Андреев, Иерархический алгоритм diff при работе со сложными документами

  http://www.math.spbu.ru/user/kromanovsky/docline/pdf/luciv.koznov.andreev.2012.sysprog.pdf
- 2012, К. В. Чувилин, Использование синтаксических деревьев для автоматизации коррекции документов в формате LATEX

  http://crm.ics.org.ru/uploads/crmissues/crm_2012_4/12417.pdf

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32656577/if-i-have-2-xml-files-how-to-create-xslt-which-will-transform-first-file-into

Comment: Почему бы вам не привести в вопросе все те ссылки, что вы дали на англоязычном SO? Что за пренебрежение к аудитории одного ресурса и лизоблюдство перед другой?

Comment: Потому что в англоязычном вопросе англоязычные ссылки, а в русскоязычном - русскоязычные. Как найду переводы на русский - добавлю.

Comment: Это задача как раз уровня докторской. У вас есть два текста, вам нужно написать программу, которая угадывает правило и переводит первый во второй. Это AI-complete.

Comment: Вот оно, отличие советского образования от российского. Инженеры - просмотреть алгоритмы и закодить. Кандидаты - предложить метод построения для широкого класса задач. Доктора - открыть новое направление науки. Тут первый случай, потому что алгоритмы уже в 2002 закодила Microsoft, значит научной новизны нет.

Comment: @hse5yzdx. может быть вы все-таки переформулируете задачу? Например, укажете, что схемы документов совпадают. Что достаточно будет того, что полученный XSLT-файл будет применим только к одному конкретному исходному документу. Что все новые вставляемые элементы вместе с их данными должны явно лежать в самом XSLT-файле. Что вы не ожидаете никакого реального преобразования схемы, а просто хотите получить эдакий одноразовый diff/patch. Чтобы инженеры смогли "просмотреть алгоритмы". Вы же знаете этих инженеров - им пока не разжуешь задачу - и пальцем не пошевелят.

Comment: @hse5yzdx ну или можно дальше продолжать собирать литературу, которая скорее всего никак не применима к вашей конкретной проблеме (кстати, какую конкретно проблему вы пытаетесь решить? у вас даже в заголовке и в теле вопроса формулировки разные. но на всякий случай "получить из 2-х XML файлов преобразующий XSLT - это общая, а не конкретная проблема)

Comment: Эти допущения действительно подходят для моего случая, но мне не ясно, как они облегчают решение. Про желательность обобшения XSLT на любые документы - это Ваши фантазии, этого нет в вопросе.

Comment: @hse5yzdx эти допущения (*особенно* то, что xslt должна быть  применима только к одному конкретному документу) опускают планку ответа с докторской до любительской. У вас прямо в ответе ссылка на два решения проблемы преобразования схемы (в том или ином виде). Но при этом преобразование схемы вам не нужно. Выбросьте их из вопроса, переформулируйте задачу, приведите пример двух XML, пример ожидаемого XSLT - и тогда может быть кто-то поможет ее решить.

Comment: да-да, мне нужна утилита. Я ей скармливаю один конкретный xml, она мне выдаёт один конкретный xslt с конкретным контентом внутри. Я не вижу, зачем приводить примеры xml, потому что внутри утилиты основные операции над xml в xslt должны быть (как их сделать я не спрашиваю, потому что такие вопросы есть отдельно на SO). То есть всё что я хочу - готовую утилиту, которая берет какой-нибудь алгоритм Tekli, применяет его ко входному xml и редактирующую последовательность сериализует в XSLT. А работы которые я подбираю нужны чтобы библиотеки найти готовые.

Comment: Кстати, про схемы изначально в моём вопросе ничего не было. Сами придумываете, сами обижаетесь, сами минусуете. Все на ровном месте.

Comment: Формат SO не предполагает длинных дискуссий. Идёмте в чат (ссылка под моим ответом). Или на другой форум, где можно обсудить тему (создавайте топик, давайте сюда ссылку). Предлагаю кывт или скуль.

Answer (score 5):

XSL-трансформация (XSLT) - такой же язык программирования, как и другие. Соответственно, код xslt не может появиться из ниоткуда сам по себе. Его нужно написать. Сделать это должен программист, вручную.

Чтобы преобразовать один xml-файл в другой, нужно вызвать xslt-процессор и передать ему преобразуемый xml. XSLT-процессоров довольно много: msxsl, saxon, xalan и другие. Какой именно использовать, зависит как от личных предпочтений, так и от окружения: операционная система, среда разработки, используемый фреймворк и язык программирования.

Например, при использовании процессора [msxsl](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) команда может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
msxsl input.xml stylesheet.xslt
```

Comment: есть мнение, что утилита MS XMLDiffPatch делает примерно то, что надо, только дифы получаются в формате Diffgram, а не XSLT. Значит не обязательно делать вручную, а можно автоматизировать.

Comment: А ещё есть утилита https://github.com/Bonuspunkt/XmlPatch только от неё дифы получаются в формате RFC5261, а не XSLT. Это ещё раз доказывает, что невручную сделать можно.

Comment: @hse5yzdx - Толку от дифов? Можно легко получить отличия романа "Война и мир" от повести "Капитанская дочка". Но как теперь автоматически получить из первого второе?

Comment: @hse5yzdx - Дело в том, что diffgram - это отличие **значений** в одном и том же документе в разное время или в разных документах, но одной и то же структуры. То есть было имя _Вася_, затем заменили его на _Петя_, но **структура** документа осталась та же самая.

Comment: молодые немцы докторские защищают - http://www.zora.uzh.ch/16421/1/fluri_dissertation_2008.pdf  а наши кричат - невозможно, невозможно

Comment: @hse5yzdx - А вам кто-то запрещает защищать докторские? На англоязычном SO вам тоже сказали, что на данный момент такого софта нет. Теоретические работы пока далеки от реального воплощения.

Comment: ну, мой научрук говорит, что любые программы - это просто инженерная задача и ни о каких защитах такой тематики речи быть не может.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29320/discussion-between-alexander-petrov-and-hse5yzdx).